# pig script unable to load nullable parquet data

Tags: apache-pig, parquet

I am trying to write a Pig Script for compacting small files having data in the parquet format. Below mentioned lines are trying to load the small files in the directory and then store them. The files have complex nested structures which are nullable and they contain lots of the `NULL`s.

```
LOGS = LOAD '/dt=20150307/hr=2015030700/*' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader();
STORE LOGS INTO '/user/compaction_output' USING parquet.pig.ParquetStorer();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2015-04-29 17:00:45,883 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2118: Cannot build an empty group
```

My suspicion is that it is because of the null values in the input files.
Can someone help out ?

Comment: Hi @mr2ert, any clue about this issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with the `ParquetLoader`.

Comment: What happens if you use dump instead of store? If that also fails, you can consider processing the data before you load it. Otherwise you can conidere processing the data before you store it.